# How do I create a custom resource path in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users controller in my application, routed with:

> ```
> map.resources :users
> ```

This has my user pages living at /users/1, and so forth.

I'd like my user pages to live at /users/blake, etc.

What's the right way to do this in rails, such that I can say link_to(@user) and the correct path is generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    login
  end
end
```

In controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_login(params[:id])
    #...
  end
end
```

[`to_param`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002325) in model is used by ActionPack to construct url for this object. And in controller you need to fetch your model by this field.